# How to disable UAS on live system

Tags: linux, usb

In the past, I had problem with *AXAGON ADSA-ST DUAL HDD* hard-drive dock. After copying few gigabytes really quickly, everything froze. Solution that works for me is to put following into new file `/etc/modprobe.d/ignore_uas.conf`:

```
options usb-storage quirks=152d:8561:u
```

(I couldn't find original source for this, hex numbers are just `idVendor` and `idProduct` of my dock (`lsusb -v`).)

I need to do same thing, but on live system to backup my original system, so editing anything in `/etc/` is not an option. Is it possible to do same thing using boot parameter or while running the system?

I'm using Linux Mint 19.3.

Comment: I also found this guide useful https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/How_to_disable_USB_Attached_Storage_(UAS)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to edit boot options in Grub. After adding `usb-storage.quirks=152d:8561:u` near the end of the line with options (before `quiet splash --` in my case, separated by a space from other options), HDD dock could be used also in live environment.

Answer (score 2):

On a live system, you might be able to do it if you can disable and re-enable the `usb_storage` module.

Check if your config lets you force unloading modules. Depending on your distribution, it's something like

```
grep FORCE_UNLOAD /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Check what may depend on that module

```
modinfo -F depends usb_storage
```

Now if you can unload the modules, set your quirks in `/sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks`, and also under `/etc` for the next reboot.

First check if there are any already, to not overwrite these:

```
cat /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
```

If there are no configured quirks already, then you can go on. (I'm putting your device IDs in a variable so that copy/pasting is easier for others with other devices).

```
id="152d:8561"

echo "$id:u" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
echo "options usb-storage quirks=$id:u" > /etc/modprobe.d/local-disable-uas.conf
```

Now you should be able to restart the module:

```
rmmod -f usb_storage
modprobe usb_storage
```